# How to print the checkbox in a row instead of column?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleHideAllColumnsProps()} /> Toggle
      All
    </div>
    {allColumns.map((column) => (
      <div key={column.id}>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" {...column.getToggleHiddenProps()} />{' '}
          {column.id}
        </label>
      </div>
    ))}

  </div>
```

My code is print out like
**the checkbox for hide and show column is print in column**
[image: the checkbox for hide and show column is print in column]

How to make it to print the checkbox in a row?

Comment: You have to use CSS and apply flex for the check boxes you need to be printed in a column format, and the normal ones to print them in row format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to achieve this with applying styling.
You can add `display` `inline-block` to inner div.

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleHideAllColumnsProps()} /> Toggle
      All
    </div>
    {allColumns.map((column) => (
      <div key={column.id} style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" {...column.getToggleHiddenProps()} />{' '}
          {column.id}
        </label>
      </div>
    ))}

  </div>
```

Or you can add display `flex` for the container div

```
 <div>
    <div>
      <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleHideAllColumnsProps()} /> Toggle
      All
    </div>
    <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
    {allColumns.map((column) => (
      <div key={column.id}>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" {...column.getToggleHiddenProps()} />{' '}
          {column.id}
        </label>
      </div>
    ))}
    </div>
  </div>
```